# org.jumpmind.db.model.ModelException: Unknown JDBC type DATETIME

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc

I am using this XML document to load a specific table into a postgresql database:

create_table.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM "http://db.apache.org/torque/dtd/database.dtd">
<database name="sample">
    <table name="Location">
        <column name="LocationID" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" />
        <column name="LocationModifyDate" type="DATETIME" required="true" />
    </table>
</database>
```

But when I load it, I get an exception:

```
An exception occurred.  Please see the following for details:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.jumpmind.db.model.ModelException: Unknown JDBC type DATETIME
  at org.jumpmind.db.model.Column.setMappedType(Column.java:283)
  at org.jumpmind.db.io.DatabaseXmlUtil.nextTable(DatabaseXmlUtil.java:202)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.reader.XmlDataReader.readNext(XmlDataReader.java:139)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.reader.XmlDataReader.open(XmlDataReader.java:75)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:84)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:78)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DbImport.importTablesFromXml(DbImport.java:208)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DbImport.importTables(DbImport.java:154)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.DbImportCommand.executeWithOptions(DbImportCommand.java:188)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractCommandLauncher.execute(AbstractCommandLauncher.java:130)
  at org.jumpmind.symmetric.DbImportCommand.main(DbImportCommand.java:72)
```

The command I use to load the XML file is this:

```
../bin/dbimport --engine corp-000 -format XML create_table.xml
```

If I use INTEGER rather than DATETIME, the XML file is processed correctly and the table is created.

What does this exception mean?  Maybe I have to use a JDBC Standard datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *timestamp* instead of *DATETIME*

```
    <column name="LocationModifyDate" type="TIMESTAMP" required="true" />
```

Read the manual for date/time in postgresql here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: That change fixed the problem.